# Saving a picture into a variable

Tags: java, image, bitmap

I'm wanting to upload a picture and save it under a variable named contactPicture. I have tried looking online but can't find much, and what I have found seems to give errors. This is what i have so far.

```
Bitmap contactPicture = null;    (Error 1)


JButton pictureanswer = new JButton("Browse");
    pictureanswer.setForeground(Color.black);
    c.gridwidth = 1;
    c.gridx = 1;
    c.gridy = 9;     
    addPanel.add(pictureanswer,c);
    pictureanswer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("JPG & GIF Images", "jpg", "gif");
            chooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File pictureDirectory = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            contactPicture = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(pictureDirectory);    (Error 2)
        }
    });
```

To explain whats happening here, I create a button "Browse". This then, when clicked, opens up the browse window to search for images. It saves this file directory under the variable, pictureDirectory.
This is the bit giving errors. I found that the final line of code should save the picture. However its giving errors.

Error 1: Bitmap cannot be reserved to a type.

Error 2: BitmapFactory cannot be reserved and error 1 again.

Please explain what Im doing wrong, all help appreciated! :)

Comment: `Bitmap` and `BitmapFactory` are classes in the Android API and not in the standard JDK API. Are you developing for android? Do you need to convert `gif` and `jpg` into bitmaps?

Comment: Not for Android, just a java program to get run on the PC

Comment: Then you can't use `Bitmap` and `BitmapFactory`, only classes in the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/). Do you need to convert the image format or just store a file in a variable?

Comment: "Reserved" or "resolved"??  Quote the exact error messages.

Comment: Resolved, sorry mistype. Im wanting to store the picture in a variable (or whatever it needs)

Answer (score 1):

You can jsut use something like:

```
java.awt.image.BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream(path));
```

Comment: Im presuming path is the file directory route such as C:\Users\dc539... If so does this need to be a string?

Comment: Also how would you later display the picture on a GUI?